# DidselectRow delegate method not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an alert in which I have used table view to show some data.

User can select any item from the table view data.

Now when I'm trying to select any item in `didSelectRow` method it isn't selecting an item. I have used breakpoints also but it isn't catching the breakpoints also.

I have given its delegates and datasources everything is fine but i'm confused why it isn't working?

My code is this:

```
extension YourOrdersViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return PreOrderService.instance.PreOrderModelInstance.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Hello")
        print(PreOrderService.instance.PreOrderModelInstance[indexPath.row].perorder_time)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView == orderTableView{
            print("Dishes")
        }
        else{
            orderTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = orderTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderCell", for: indexPath) as!
    PreOrderTableViewCell

        cell.titleLbl.text = PreOrderService.instance.PreOrderModelInstance[indexPath.row].perorder_time
        print(cell.titleLbl.text!)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

View Controller looks like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04LL2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check or you have set this value:
[image]
If `No Selection` is set instead of `Single Selection`, the `func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method will not be executed.

Comment: It is set to single selection but still it isn't working. @maxwell

Answer (score 0):

Does it have any gesture recognizer on your UIViewControlller. If it does and the gesture recognizer is above your table views on responder chain, it will take any single touch and leave nothing for your table views.

Comment: No there is not any type of gesture. @Trần Phạm Hoàng Duy

Answer (score 0):

Whole problem in your code I think is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the delegate and datasource are set. 
If you're creating the views via storyboard, make sure that you set the iboutlets for delegate/datasource.

Both of these lines mean the same thing: so remove the second one.

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Comment: It is still not selecting. @valosip

Comment: @Awais  Did you remove one or both of those lines?

Comment: i have removed the second line only as u said. @valosip

Answer (score -1):

In Main.storyboard select your table view and in Attribute inspector change selection to single selection

Comment: check user interaction enabled or set delegation and dataSource in storyboard

Comment: yup it is also enabled. @Dhinakaran